# Error 1300 while submitting UWP app to Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Since I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, every new submission to Windows Store generates an error code 1300 as such:

> The submission failed with error code(s) 1300. More info about the error(s) can be found [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620833).

I've never experienced this kind of error with older updates of Visual Studio.

I've tried several submissions but it fails constantly.

I can't upgrade my app anymore, does anyone experience the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround.

It seems there's an issue at this time with NuGet package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.2.0

I've downgraded from 5.2.0 to 5.1.0 for each project of my solution, which has solved my issue.

Comment: They now have an upgrade from 5.2. I upgraded and got past the error